# Bound on difference of log of unitary matrices

Tags: matrix-analysis

Suppose I have two unitary matrices $u, v$ such that $\|u-v\|<\epsilon$ in the operator norm. Is there a way to bound the quantity $\|\log u-\log v\|$? We can assume that $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small and we choose a branch cut for the logarithm such that eigenvalues of $u$ and $v$ will not be split up. Ideally I would like to get a bound in the form $\|\log u-\log v\|<C\epsilon$ where $C$ is a constant independent of the dimension of the matrix. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! Could you specify what you mean by "such that the eigenvalues of $u$ and $v$ will not be split up"?

Comment: For example, if $u$ and $v$ are scalars and we use the branch cut $(-\pi,\pi]$, we might have the situation $u=e^{i(\pi-\delta)}$, $v=e^{i(\pi+\delta)}$ so that $u$ and $v$ are very close but their logs will differ by almost $2\pi$. I don't want to consider this case.

Comment: Note that $uv^{-1}$ is a unitary and is close to $1$ (with distance less than $\epsilon$). This means that $uv^{-1}$ has a logarithm close to zero in norm. The rest you should be able to figure out.

Comment: @Bailey: I understand your intuition. Still, I think in order to prove an estimate of the kind you seek, it will be important to give a precise mathematical description of this assumption. Or are you asking whether for all (sufficiently small) $\varepsilon> 0$ there exists $C > 0$ such that for all $u,v$ with $\|u-v\| < \varepsilon$ **there exists** a branch cut for the logarithm such that $\|\log u - \log v\| < C \varepsilon$?

Comment: @DavidHandelman: I'm not sure I follow: We don't have $\log u - \log v = \log(uv^{-1})$ in general since (i) this rule does not hold in dimension $1$ for general complex values of $u$ and $v$ and since (ii) the matrices $u$ and $v$ are not assumed to commute. But maybe I misunderstood you?

Comment: @JochenGlueck you are right. The question should be, does there exist $C$ such that for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$ and with $\|u-v\|<\epsilon$ we can find a branch cut such that $\|\log u-\log v\|<C\epsilon$?